# Click link on plugin/theme page and open the contextual help on a specific tab

Tags: jquery, theme-options, contextual-help

I've added a help section using the [add_help_tab()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_help_tab) function. I'd like to be able to click a link somewhere on the theme/plugin page and have the help panel open at whichever tab I need. Can someone help me out with the required JS for this?

Each tab panel has a unique hash link associated with it so I'd need to use this somehow I'm guessing

```
/themes.php?page=theme_options#tab-panel-general
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the Q is bordering the `off-topic`, but IMO interesting in WordPress context.

I've tested this directly in FireBug, in the Dashboard page (`wp-admin/index.php`).

```
var $ =jQuery.noConflict();

// Remove 'active' class from all link tabs
$('li[id^="tab-link-"]').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});

// Hide all panels
$('div[id^="tab-panel-"]').each(function(){
    $(this).css('display','none');
});

// Set our desired link/panel
$('#tab-link-help-content').addClass('active');
$('#tab-panel-help-content').css('display','block');

// Force click on the Help tab
$('#contextual-help-link').click();
```

Comment: Thanks. The animation becomes a bit jerky when I try and use it within a click function for my links, however it works and will do for now :)

Comment: @Andrew, maybe you can take it to StackOverflow to see if improvements are possible. Glad it helped, g'luck :)